# Conditional predicates in LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there a way to combine the queries in `if` and `else` sections?

```
public List<MyClass> GetData(Category category, bool flag= true)
{
     IQueryable<MyClass> result;
     if (flag)
     {
        result =  Session.All<MyClass>()
                    .Where(mc => mc.Col.Equals(category.ToString()) && mc.FLAG);
     }
     else
     {
        result = Session.All<MyClass>()
                    .Where(mc => mc.Col.Equals(category.ToString()));
     }

     return result.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure.

```
result =  Session.All<MyClass>()
                 .Where(mc => mc.Col.Equals(category.ToString()) && (!flag || mc.FLAG));
```

You can determine the rewrite logic by making a matrix of allowed `true` outcomes:

```
▼ mc.FLAG   ► flag
            true     false
true        valid    valid
false       invalid  valid
```

Here you see that the condition is valid if `flag` is false (both equate to `true`) or `mc.FLAG` is `true`.

I would also advice to do the flag check first, since that is the better performing predicate. This might prevent the second check if the first results to false:

```
result =  Session.All<MyClass>()
                 .Where(mc => (!flag || mc.FLAG) && mc.Col.Equals(category.ToString());
```

Comment: That's neat. Thanks!

Comment: @devnull You are welcome. Included the logic for this now. Had a little trouble with finding the right unicode characters :)

Comment: I know this answers the question. Just curious, do you prefer this to the code in the OP considering readability and (marginal)performance?

Comment: Hmmm, you have an extra condition in the predicate(!flag). How is that going to give a performance gain compared to OP where it is a less complex predicate? Anyway It is not a big deal as practically there is no impact.

Comment: This code is less clear in it's intent than the original. It's tenser, but you need a truth table. OP: don't do this.

Comment: I don't see the complexity of this one @nathan. This is very clear. The truth table is just to explain how to analyze this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's hard to say without understanding the context of the code. But if i was describing the decision logic in words, "if that do that etc", I suspect it would be match the OP's code more than this one. The advantage of a first attempt at something, over a clever refactoring, is that quite often it matches the intended thought process.

Answer (score 21):

You can chain `Where` conditionally.

```
public List<MyClass> GetData(Category category, bool flag = true)
{
    var result = Session.All<MyClass>()
        .Where(mc => mc.Col.Equals(category.ToString()));

    if (flag) {
        result = result.Where(mc => mc.FLAG);
    }

    return result.ToList();
}
```